# How to make a service to run a python script which includes browser automation

Tags: python, services, systemd-unit

I have python script which is using `selenium` web driver to do some web automation task. This python code is running perfectly fine when I am running it from the terminal. It launches firefox and does what is required.

I have made a service which looks like below:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start python web browser code

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3.5 /home/pi/web_automation.py
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=30s 
StandardOutput=null

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When starting this service, it always remains in the `failed state`. I have also tried editing the `/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE/autostart/` and include below lines

```
@/usr/bin/python3.5 /home/pi/web_automation.py
```

But it's still not working. How can I make it work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't just a RasPi with Monitor by hand to test it but here are some pointers as far as I can see to "fix" your unit.

First you should delete the line `StandardOutput=null`. Default Standard Output in a service is the journal. Redirecting it to `/dev/null` will suppress any (error)messages from your script. Otherwise you will see what's going wrong. That may help:

```
rpi ~$ systemctl status web_automation.service
rpi ~$ systemctl journalctl --boot --pager-end --unit=web_automation.service
```

The next is that firefox needs a graphical user interface so it must be `WantedBy=graphical.target`. It also needs a `DISPLAY` environment variable to find its output.

Because your script runs in a console from a logged in user, I guess it is **pi**, you should for a first try run the script also with this user. If it runs then you can optimize it for another user. Default is root. Does your script run as root?

Putting it together I would see this unit (`Type=simple` is default):

```
[Unit]
Description=Start python web browser code

[Service]
User=pi
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3.5 /home/pi/web_automation.py
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=30s

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selenium job requires launching Firefox, which I don't believe will be possible when you run it as a service.

You might be able to save this by changing browsers from Firefox to the `HtmlUnit` "browser" supported by selenium.  That has no graphical interface so it seems like it *might* work.  I'd do further research on it (or a small test) before you try to convert any big script to use it.  I have not used selenium recently, but my recollection is that there were some issues with `HtmlUnit` where it didn't support a full range of real-browser capabilities.  That may or may not still be true.

The other alternative would be to leave selenium and do something in pure scripting.  If the webpage that you want to hit is not complicated, then you can do a lot with the command-line tool `curl` called from a scripting language, sometimes even bash but more likely Ruby, Perl, or (if you must) Python.  I also used a Ruby module to interact with a more complicated page once, but I can no longer remember the module name.  You could probably search and find it (or the equivalent in a different language).  These differ from selenium in that they are not web *drivers*, they emulate the key interactions with the webpage internally.  This means they don't need to launch something external to themselves, which might make them more suitable for running as a service.