# The service error for startup app in a terminal

Tags: raspbian, python, services, lxterminal, systemd-startup

My Python application needs to run on a Raspberry Pi 3 at startup and in a terminal.

What I did:

1. I created a service `screenscript.service` in `/etc/systemd/system`
2. a bash file in `/home/pi/mydir/screen.sh`
3. a python application in `/home/pi/mydir/code/hello.py`

code 1, `screenscript.service`

```
Description=Terminal Service
After=network.target
[Service]
ExecStart=/home/pi/mydir/screen.sh
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

code 2, `screen.sh`

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
cd home/pi/mydir/code
echo "work dir: '$(pwd)'" >> /tmp/log.log
/usr/bin/lxterminal -e "python /home/pi/mydir/code/hello.py"
```

code 3, `hello.py`

```
import threading

def printit():
  threading.Timer(5.0, printit).start()
  print "Hello, World!"

printit()
```

My issue:

I want to see 'hello world' continue display in a terminal, when I turn on the raspberry PI power.
My service failed
`$systemctl status screenscript` ---> shows loaded, enabled, active failed, code exited.

I can run this line `$/usr/bin/lxterminal -e "python /home/pi/mydir/code/hello.py"`

Answer (score 1):

At a glance I see some errors. You missed the `[Unit]` statement before `Description=Terminal Service` in *screenscript.service*.

*hello.py* does not have any indention. This cannot work for a `def`.

With `lxterminal` you try to start a graphical program but your service is `WantedBy=multi-user.target`. This does not provide a graphical environment. You must use `WantedBy=graphical.target`.

If you want a graphical output you have to specify a display like `Environment=DISPLAY=:0`. Here is an example: [How to make a service to run a python script which includes browser automation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88839/79866).